# How can I bundle my VS Code extension so that I can install it anywhere without internet connexion?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vsix

I'm working on an VS Code extension that's using a bunch of modules, some of which are needed in release.
I need to be able to install this extension in a new environnement without any internet connexion. How would I go about that since I assume my released extension will need to fetch its modules? Is there a way to bundle my extension with a "local version" of the needed modules?

I tried using VS Code's vsce. It created a .vscx file from my extension so that I could install it from my extension manager inside VS. Sadly some extensions wouldn't load and it crashed...

I also tried to manually install my extension globaly, by taking the "/dist" and "/out" files from my dev project and put them in a common file in my "${USER}/.vscode/extensions" folder.
I'm not 100% sure but I believe it crashed to because it couldn't load the modules.

Here is the module list (all of them, dev and realease) :

```
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^22.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^14.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.5.0",
    "@tsconfig/svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/glob": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/node": "16.x",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.71.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.31.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.31.0",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.1.5",
    "rollup": "^2.3.4",
    "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^3.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^6.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "eslint": "^8.20.0",
    "glob": "^8.0.3",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "concurrently": "^7.4.0",
    "devextreme": "17.2.18",
    "svelte": "^3.31.0",
    "svelte-check": "^1.1.23",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.6.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "trash": "^8.1.0"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could store all installed extensions in a zip file with this (batch)script, and copy that to any location you need:

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims='" %%f in (`code --list-extensions  --verbose ^| findstr /c:"Started watching" ^| findstr "extensions"`) do ( set u=%%f)

echo VSCode extensions are installed in: %u%

"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a %TEMP%\extensions.7z %u% 

echo All currently installed extensions are compressed in the file: %TEMP%\extensions.7z
```

Comment: So I would install the extension with internet connexion, allowing it to get its modules. And that working extension folder, I would just transfer it directly onto the internetless's environnement?
That's clever, idk why I didn't think of it myself haha

Comment: This is still an imperfect solution, as several extensions download dependencies on demand and you need to perform certain actions so as to trigger the downloads. But anyway, better than nothing.